# Como agregar una ruta adicional en getInputStream

Tags: java

Buen dia

Tengo el siguiente código para imprimir documentos seleccionando el case 0 se imprime un documento local

```
  case 0:

        // Impresion local
        printOptions.put("numberOfCopies", "1");
        printOptions.put("collate", "off");
        printOptions.put("punch", "off");
        printOptions.put("punchMode", "3HOLE");
        printOptions.put("printMediaSource", "TRAY2");
        printOptions.put("nUp", "OFf");
        printOptions.put("nUpBorder", "SOLID");

        flagResult = _printService.print(getInputStream(), printOptions);

        if (flagResult)
        {
           result = "Trabajo completado";
        }
        break;
```

invocando

```
  public InputStream getInputStream()
       {
        InputStream is = null;
        String resourcePath =  "text/F-1203SolServSucVtu.pdf";
        Bundle ourBundle = _sbc.getBundleContext().getBundle();
       try
        {
           is = BundleUtilities.getResourceAsStream(ourBundle, resourcePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          Activator.getLog().debug("Exception thrown while creating InpuStream",
           e);
  }
  return is;
    }
```

Pero no he logrado agregar una ruta adicional para que al seleccionar el case 1 se imprima otro documento ,al oprimir el case 2 otro y así , alguien tiene una idea de como lo puedo lograr 
otra ruta seria algo asi

```
 String resourcePath =  "text/FF-1205BenefSoliTasa.pdf";
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si estoy entendiendo bien, pero esta pudiera ser una opción:

```
public InputStream getInputStream(String resourcePath)
   {
    InputStream is = null;
// Esta variable "resourcePath" ya no la tenemos fija sino que
// la vamos a recibir de parámetro
//   String resourcePath =  "text/F-1203SolServSucVtu.pdf";
    Bundle ourBundle = _sbc.getBundleContext().getBundle();
   try
    {
       is = BundleUtilities.getResourceAsStream(ourBundle, resourcePath);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Activator.getLog().debug("Exception thrown while creating InpuStream",
       e);
    }
  return is;
  }
```

Luego dentro del case:

```
String resourcePath;
case 0:
   resourcePath = "text/F-1203SolServSucVtu.pdf";
   //etc, etc
   flagResult = _printService.print(getInputStream(resourcePath), printOptions);
   //etc, etc,
   break;
case 1:
   resourcePath = "text/FF-1205BenefSoliTasa.pdf"; 
   //etc, etc
   flagResult = _printService.print(getInputStream(resourcePath), printOptions);
   //etc, etc,
   break;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda , lo revise y seria la solución adecuada ya que pasa el parámetro del path para imprimirlo , pero solo funciona el case 0 ,revisare mi codigo para verificar ,que no existan interferencias entre variables

Comment: Edito el error fue mio ,gracias por su ayuda